# Are there any disadvantages to using replace = true on an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting used to AngularJS and have been building quite a few directives.

Typically, where the directive is an `Element` I have been setting the `replace` option to `true`

I wondered though, does doing this have any negative impact on anything? I'm setting it to `true` so that it just keeps the source html nice and tidy, and as close to `html` specs as possible.

However, if it's likely that setting this to true has some negative impact I'd forego the specs...

So - are there advantages/disadvantages to `replace:true` ?

Comment: What for @RameshRajendran? any simple directive that replaces the element with the template is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

There are no negative impacts, but there is a specific use case for setting `replace` to `true`.

If you want to replace whatever markup may be in the element already with your own markup, set it to `true`.

If you want to live in harmony with whatever markup is already in the directive, set it to `false`.

Comment: I guess it makes me wonder, if there are no negatives (or positives) then why is there the option in the first place..

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind when using `replace: true` is that your template can only have one root node. So, if you want to have a template with several siblings at its root level, use `replace: false` and your template will be inserted into the inner HTML of the original element instead of replacing it, completely.

This rule is enforced because angular tries to transfer all attributes of the original element to the template's root node.

With that in mind, I think it's a stylistic choice: What makes most sense, semantically, for your application?

Comment: Yah, i fell into the `one root node` 'gotcha' yesterday :)